# Nextjs ssr is serving correct data, but page component receives old cached data

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

My NextJs app has a weird behavior. when i use SSR for rendering page it load the correct data at first, but when i use `router.replace(asPath);` to refresh the data after inserting a new value to my mongodb database, the ssr fetches new data, but page renders same old data. And if i click on the route link then the correct data is loaded.

**Page refreshing code**

```
const router = useRouter();
const { asPath } = router;
router.replace(asPath);
```

Comment: How are you checking that the right data is being fetched? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Console logged the data in useeffect, and the logged data is correct, but the rendered data is the old data, like cached data